# The single tag for Office Open XML

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Currently on SO I found more the one tag for Office Open XML:

[ooxml](/questions/tagged/ooxml) (76), [openxml](/questions/tagged/openxml) (341), [office-open-xml](/questions/tagged/office-open-xml) (0 so far).

Also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) lists all of them:

> Office Open XML (also informally known as OOXML or OpenXML) ..

Maybe merge all answers into the single one?

Comment: I suggest ooxml

Comment: [docx] and [xlsx] are specific sub-types of Office Open XML, not synonyms.  So they should not be merged s if they were.

Comment: @APC: No problem, I removed them even listed as additional, example info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, merged and synonymized into [openxml](/questions/tagged/openxml) since it was dominant.